# Merge sort algorithm with user comparison

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to implement a merge sort algorithm to decide what a user's favourite movie is. When the algorithm needs to decide which option is "lower" than another, it will ask the user for an input. To make sure the algorithm works first (before trying with movies) I've just made a String list in kotlin with String numbers. After running this test, it returns the wrong answer. I used https://www.jdoodle.com/compile-kotlin-online/ to test whether it works.

```
fun main() {
    println("Hello, world!!!")
    val numbers = listOf("3", "4", "2", "1", "52", "7", "5", "8")
    val sortedList = mergeSort(numbers)
    println("Unsorted: $numbers")
    println("Sorted: $sortedList")
}

fun mergeSort(list: List<String>): List<String> {
        if (list.size <= 1) {
            return list
        }

        val middle = list.size / 2
        var left = list.subList(0,middle);
        var right = list.subList(middle,list.size);

        return merge(mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right))
    }

fun merge(left: List<String>, right: List<String>): List<String>  {
    var indexLeft = 0
    var indexRight = 0
    var newList : MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
    
    //here is where the user decides which number is lower.
    print("which number is lower " + left[indexLeft] + " or " + right[indexRight] + ": ")
    val stringInput = readLine()


    while (indexLeft < left.count() && indexRight < right.count()) {
        if (stringInput.equals(left[indexLeft])) {
            newList.add(left[indexLeft])
            indexLeft++
        } else {
            newList.add(right[indexRight])
            indexRight++
        }
    }
    
    while (indexLeft < left.size) {
        newList.add(left[indexLeft])
        indexLeft++
    }

    while (indexRight < right.size) {
        newList.add(right[indexRight])
        indexRight++
    }
    return newList;
}
```

The program returns this:

```
Hello, world!!!
which number is lower 3 or 4: 3
which number is lower 2 or 1: 1
which number is lower 3 or 1: 1
which number is lower 52 or 7: 7
which number is lower 5 or 8: 5
which number is lower 7 or 5: 5
which number is lower 1 or 5: 1
Unsorted: [3, 4, 2, 1, 52, 7, 5, 8]
Sorted: [1, 5, 8, 7, 52, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: the input should be in the while loop.

```
fun merge(left: List<String>, right: List<String>): List<String>  {
    var indexLeft = 0
    var indexRight = 0
    var newList : MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()

    


    while (indexLeft < left.count() && indexRight < right.count()) {
    
        //here is where the user decides which number is lower.
        print("which number is lower " + left[indexLeft] + " or " + right[indexRight] + ": ")
        val stringInput = readLine()
        
        if (stringInput.equals(left[indexLeft])) {
            newList.add(left[indexLeft])
            indexLeft++
        } else if (stringInput.equals(right[indexRight])) {
            newList.add(right[indexRight])
            indexRight++
        }
    }

    while (indexLeft < left.size) {
        newList.add(left[indexLeft])
        indexLeft++
    }

    while (indexRight < right.size) {
        newList.add(right[indexRight])
        indexRight++
    }
    return newList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would propose more *kotlin way* solution (as well as more classic functional one i guess):

```
fun mergeSort(data: List<String>): List<String> =
    if (data.size <= 1) data
    else data.chunked(
        Math.ceil(data.size / 2.0).toInt()
    ).map{ mergeSort(it) }.let {
        merge(it[0], it[1])
    }

tailrec fun merge(l: List<String>, r: List<String>, res: List<String>): List<String> = when {
    l.isEmpty() -> res + r
    r.isEmpty() -> res + l
    l.first() <= r.first() -> merge(l.drop(1), r, res + l.first())
    else -> merge(l, r.drop(1), res + r.first())
}

fun merge(l: List<String>, r: List<String>): List<String> = merge(l, r, emptyList())
```

this one uses tail recursive merge function on immutable collection (which in fact can as well be mutable without any algorithm change).

```
println(mergeSort(listOf("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g").shuffled()))
// [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
```